# Can't upload SQL files into phpmyadmin

Tags: 16.04, phpmyadmin

Hello Ask Ubuntu Community,

I'm having some difficulty fixing a problem with phpmyadmin.

I can't upload any files. i get

> No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or
>   the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP
>   configuration.

I've upped the configuration files to very large numbers. What could i be missing?

Comment: Have you restarted the daemon? (Have to ask the 'turn it off and on again' question)

Comment: yep! Tried that. Along with modifying some other options